# Repeating Alarms not working below one minute

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an App which doing stuff in a Service in background (also when Screen is swiched off). I start the service in an Activity with a repeating Alarm. Whatever I set below 60 seconds its ignored and the alarm comes exactly after 60 seconds. 
I tested it with the emulator on Android 6.0, on a Samsung Galaxy with Android 6.0 and with a Sony Z3 with Android 5.1.1. On all the same. An ICS it worked perfectly. Isn't it possible anymore to repeate alarms below one minute?

If I set it to 120 seconds its working every 120 seconds. The same with 90 seconds ...

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, AppService.class);
i.putExtra(AppService.VOL_ALM, test_value));

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
alarmManager.cancel(pi);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 *time_in_seconds, pi);
```

**EDIT:**

I set up 60 s and left the phone work in background. Thats the result

```
Mai 15  17:08:01.803
Mai 15  17:10:39.213
Mai 15  17:25:39.317
Mai 15  17:40:39.259
Mai 15  17:55:39.255
Mai 15  18:10:39.292
Mai 15  18:25:39.255
Mai 15  18:40:39.238
```

what can I do to run the service at least every minute?

Comment: "Isn't it possible anymore to repeate alarms below one minute?" - AFAIK, no, it's not. If you need timing with an interval that short, you shouldn't be using `AlarmManager` anyway.

Comment: Try using a timer of your choice. I.e.: a `CountDownTimer` could work well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So than I have to live with this timing. Changin it to a timer would change the app completely.

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution. I always reset the alarm in the service, that works perfekt even down to 5s.

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, AppService.class);
i.putExtras(extraBundle); // read out inside the service

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, pi.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

// Remove old alarm
alarmManager.cancel(pi);
// Set new alarm
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);
```

Comment: This worked for me up until recently, when some devices using Android O started batching the alarms to a minimum period of 5 minutes. Looking at you, Galaxy S9...